# using bcp to copy between servers gives SQLState 22008

Tags: t-sql, bcp

I'm trying to copy data from one database to another (on different servers) whose tables have identical schema, every time I run the below query I get an error saying the following...

"SQLState = 22008    NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid date format"

The query is this...

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1    
GO    
RECONFIGURE    
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1    
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO


DECLARE @MasterServerName varchar(40)    
DECLARE @MasterServerUserName varchar(20)    
DECLARE @MasterServerPassword varchar(20)    
DECLARE @SlaveServerName varchar(40)    
DECLARE @SlaveServerUserName varchar(20)    
DECLARE @SlaveServerPassword varchar(20)

DECLARE @ExportFile varchar (40)    
DECLARE @ExportFile1 varchar (40)    
DECLARE @ExportFile2 varchar (40)    
DECLARE @ExportFile3 varchar (40)    
DECLARE @ExportFile4 varchar (40)

SET @MasterServerName='{SQL_Server_Name}'    
SET @MasterServerUserName='{SQL_USER_LOGIN}'    
SET @MasterServerPassword='{SQL_USER_PASSWORD}'

SET @SlaveServerName='{SLAVE_NAME}\{SLAVE_INSTANCE}'    
SET @SlaveServerUserName='{SLAVE_USER_LOGIN}'    
SET @SlaveServerPassword='{SLAVE_USER_PASSWORD}'

-------------------------------------
SET @ExportFile1='C:\ExportTracking1.txt'    
SET @ExportFile2='C:\ExportTracking2.txt'    
SET @ExportFile3='C:\ExportTracking3.txt'    
SET @ExportFile4='C:\ExportTracking4.txt'


DECLARE @BCP varchar(8000)

----------------------------------------------
--Collecting tracking data from the slave server
-----------------------------------------------

SET @BCP =
'bcp "select * FROM <DATABASE_NAME>.dbo.<TABLE_NAME> where ExportID="9999999"" queryoutout '+@ExportFile1+' -c -U'+@SlaveServerUserName+' -P'+@SlaveServerPassword+' -S'+@SlaveServerName+' -C{850}'
PRINT @BCP
EXEC xp_CMDshell @BCP

-----------------------------------------------
--Adding tracking data to the master server
-----------------------------------------------


SET @BCP =
'bcp <DATABASE_NAME>.dbo.<TABLE_NAME> in '+@ExportFile1+' -e C:\error1.txt -c -U'+@MasterServerUserName+' -P'+@MasterServerPassword+' -S'+@MasterServerName+' -C{850}'
PRINT @BCP
EXEC xp_CMDshell @BCP


-----------------------------------------------

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0    
GO    
RECONFIGURE    
GO 

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0    
GO    
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Can anyone please help shed some light on why this error is occurring?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Lee

Comment: Apologies, also the variable values are just tags where I've taken the true values out, the same goes for actual database and table names. The error is occurring in the "Adding tracking data to the master server" section.

Comment: on the same server with the same credentials ? If not may be the default language for the connections.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No, they're different servers with different credentials, but the language and collation are set the same and the credentials are set within the query so the authentication piece *seems* to be ok.

Comment: just to be sure `select @@language` returns the same in the two context ? server1 database1 creds1 and server2 database2 creds2. Less probable but a check on the language and regional settings of the windows servers running the sql instances.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr / Mrs Schmit! The master server had a language setting of British whereas the slaves were us_english; I've now submitted a change request to ensure they match before trying again.  Fingers crossed! :)

Comment: If you can add that as an answer I'd be happy to click the up arrow (I'm assuming that's how reputation works on this site?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less probable but also possible, please check the language and regional settings of the windows servers running the sql instances.